# How do I test functions on jsPerf without it executing?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test two snippets, but jsPerf keeps executing the code

```
myWindow=window.open("myurl.tld","_top");
myWindow.document

\\vs

window.location = "https://myurl.tld"
```

How do I make it so I don't get redirected while the codes are being tested?

Comment: So you want it to test the code without running the code???

Comment: Ahah, no I just thought it tested the code somewhere else, I get redirected before I see the results of the test!?

Comment: What is it that you want to test? Since you are doing a network request the time spent getting the data is several magnitudes larger than what you could gain....

Comment: I was trying to test the speed of both the re-directions. I'm sorry, I'm not following which snippet is doing a network request?

Comment: When you do a redirect, where do the page come from? You are literally writing `myurl.tld` in your examples. How do the page get from the server to your browser if you don't do a  network request? You are trying to prematurely optimize your code, and that is evil.

Comment: prematurely optimize my code? I'm just trying not to advertise my url on here, since there are users under the age of 19, although believe me I'd appreciate the traffic. I assure you, I'm just trying to learn program efficiently! Appreciate you taking the time though!

Managed to get it to work if you're curious: https://jsperf.com/window-location-vs-window-openv

Comment: Yes, prematurely optimize your code. (it has nothing to to with the exact url). You are spending time to see which is faster. Let say that there was a difference and one method takes 0.0000001 seconds and the other is 100% slower: 0.0000002. But, since it has to fetch the page from your server, and that depends on the current load of your server and the network, it can take from 0.001 to 60 seconds. Are you redirecting the page thousands of times per second? Does it matter if it takes  0.0000001 seconds longer?

Comment: Valid point, I guess I just wasted 30 mins LOL

Comment: And that's the meaning of *premature optimizations*, and why you should not do it. ( Sometimes we do it [anyways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55894287/36866) to learn new things)